# Resource Error With Merged Android Activity

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I am creating a Cordova 3.5 application and I call external code that creates a different activity for login related tasks. However, when this activity starts, the application crashes with android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0.

I have copied all the string resource files to res/values/strings.xml with the config-file tag (this was previously an error), and I have merged the AndroidManifest.xml files using the same method.

Is there some other resources that I am missing to properly merge these activities? I am new to Android so I am unaware of an nuances that may appear in a situation like this.

EDIT:
By manually adding the source files manually (the referenced library was open source) I am able to improve the situation but now I get a new error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070001
Improvement, but not quite there yet.

Comment: did you call super.init in your onCreate?

Comment: The code that creates the other activity is completely external and has been tested on its own. I call an entry-point method which does the activity creation internally.

Comment: My Cordova plugin does call super.initialize in its initialize method though.

Comment: @bhowden Does the edits shine any light on what might be wrong?